# Concenate a string on cell value if true

Tags: excel, vba

How can I possibly reset the ct to start over when it's a new duplicate?

```
Dim Last As Long
Dim ct As Long

Last = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ct = ct + 1

For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & Last)
If cell. DupeUnique = xlDuplicate Then
cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Value & "-" & ct
End If
Next
```

Data Example before code:

```
0345867   345867

0345867   345867

0345831   345831

0345831   345831

0345831   345831
```

Data Example of what it does:

```
0345867   345867-1

0345867   345867-2

0345831   345831-3

0345831   345831-4

0345831   345831-5
```

Data Example of what I want it to do:

```
0345867   345867-1

0345867   345867-2

0345831   345831-1

0345831   345831-2

0345831   345831-3
```

Comment: What is the original data before what it does and what you want it to do.

Comment: I edited to show the original data.

Comment: If your data is in columns A and B, will B always be equal to A?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Sub AdCounter()
Dim Last As Long
Dim ct As Long

Last = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ct = 1

For i = 2 To Last 'I start from 2 because I think in the 1th are header
Cells(i, "A").Select
If Cells(i, "A") = Cells(i - 1, "A") Then
    Cells(i, "B") = Cells(i, "A") & "-" & ct
    ct = ct + 1
Else
    ct = 1
    Cells(i, "B") = Cells(i, "A") & "-" & ct
    ct = ct + 1
End If
Next
End Sub
```

The code above is valid only if your date are ordered from column A

Answer (score 0):

Put your counter inside your loop. Track the last row and compare. If it is a duplicate, reset your counter.

```
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ct As Long
Dim lDuplicate as Long
Dim ws as excel.worksheet
lRow = 1
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count
    'Check if this row is the same as the last
    if ws.range("A" & lrow) = lDuplicate then
        'If it is, reset your counter
        ct = 1
    End If

    'Write your incremented value
    ws.range("B" & lrow).value = ws.range("A" & lrow).value & "-" & ct

    lDuplicate = ws.range("A" & lrow).value
    ct = ct + 1

    lRow = lRow + 1
Loop
```